# Determine $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(\frac{a}{3^k})}{3^k\sin(\frac{a}{3^{k-1}})}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find 
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(\frac{a}{3^k})}{3^k\sin(\frac{a}{3^{k-1}})}$$

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem, i was looking to see some ways of solving it. Any hints will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Start by simplifying $\frac{\sin (3x)}{\sin x}$

> \begin{align} \text{Notice that} \sin(3x)=\sin(2x+x) \text{ and you should get: } \frac{\sin (3x)}{\sin x}=3-4\sin^2 x \end{align}

This leads you to examine the following, simpler series:

> \begin{align} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 (a/3^k)}{3^k}\end{align}

*Hint 2:* Replace $\sin^2(x)$ with $(1-\cos 2x)/2$ to get an even simpler series.

> \begin{align} \left(\text{the series is }\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (2a/3^k)}{3^k}\right)\end{align}

*Hint 3:* One way of dealing with this final series is to

> \begin{align} \text{replace the cosinus with its Taylor series, invoke Fubini's theorem, then permute the two series.} \end{align}

NB: There may be a simpler way than hint 3